# script & link tags fallback

Tags: javascript, css, html, fallback

How do you include your libs into your projects?
Do you use fallback?

for now i'am using my own (i think now the best variant) fallback

```
function onErrorLoader(obj, link){
    if(obj.tagName != "SCRIPT")
        obj.href = link;
    else
        obj.src = link;
}
```

and i use it like this

First i include my error handler in my html
`<script src="js/onErrorLoader.js"></script>`

next to this i can call my libs like this

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" onerror="onErrorLoader(this, 'vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"  onerror="onErrorLoader(this, 'vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')"></script>
```

What do you think about this?
What you can advice for make it better, or maybe you know much better way to do this

All this just in case **CDN** does not reply

For example: I am using my scripts from my own **CDN**, but in some reasons my **CDN** does not reply

Comment: Why do you do that? ... I've programming for more than 20 years and never had to do anything like that

Comment: I updated my post and added the reason why i'm asking this

Comment: Well, that's reason to use the well known CDN's

Comment: Yeah) but i want to use my own cdn and i want to be insured that my webapp won't fall down)

Comment: Does this happen often? ... I've again never had problem with my web servers not delivering any files

Comment: not rly. But i saw how people using `if(!JQuery || !window.$)` load jQ from another source. And i saw that solution more than few times

Comment: I'm hosting my files on the same server as my web app, either all downloads or nothing, safe as a safe deposit box :)

Comment: An example where this might be helpful is loading a remote script like google and the script fails to install, then you might be stuck attempting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this done. I believe that is because it is unnecessary. I've never seen a scenario where my styles or scripts just, didn't load. Even back when I may have had 12 scripts loaded in the head. The browser just doesn't forget to load the assets.

Most modern workflows have preprocessing and concatenation and then they serve 2 or 3 files. People use task-runners and build tools like grunt, gulp, brunch, broccoli, codekit etc.

My advice would be to just let the browser load the files and not to worry about it, or if you really want to be SURE something happens / look up "promises"

Comment: yeah, you are pretty right about that. Anyway, i want to realize some good solution, because i want to use my own cdn for my webapp, and i want to be insured that my webapp won't fall down.

Comment: Have you noticed any CDNs that do that? Maybe you could reach out and ask them, but in my experience - They seem to be regular old links to files / but are just dynamic. Good luck. : )